# How to merge pair-wise table(s) and non-pairwise table(s) in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to perform clustering analysis. I have extracted all the possible data. And have made several pairwise comparisons. Now I want to know how do I merge the data?

Table 1:

```
entry   smth   coefficient
entry1  smth1  1.23
entry2  smth1  2.05
entry3  smth2  0.95
entry2  smth4  1.65
```

Table 2:

```
smth
     smth1  smth2 smth 4
smth1 100    59    35
smth2  59    100   82
smth4  35    82    100
```

Table 3:

```
entry
       entry1 entry2 entry3
entry1 100     82     75
entry2  82     100     59
entry3  75     59     100
```

I am trying to understand how to program this. I am new to matlab, I am training a lot, so there's definitely some progress, but now enough to get how to solve my problem.
UPDATE:

Here is the illustration to the table 2:

[image: illustration to table 2]

There is some similarity and difference between different smths.

Now here is the illustration to the table 3:

[image: illustration to table 3]

Entries also have some relational distance.

I also have input cases - table 1. Each row of the table is a unique input case. However, the real table is long, so some of the cases may be actually the same, though named differently. Now, I want to combine pairwise comparison 1, pairwise comparison 2 and if required up to pairwise comparison n. Finally, there are also some non-relative parameters (in table 1 there's one only - called coefficient), by which I want to multiply the position of pairwise-verified point in space (i.e. I am introducing a new axis - corresponding to `coefficient` and move the points by this axis. So there will be some sort of distribution, which I will be able to use in clustering analysis. I.e. I have an axis1/plane1 - corresponding to the pairwise comparisons of the `smths`, I have an axis2/plane2 - pairwise comparisons of the `entries`. Then I apply all those to the cases, for example in table 1 entry2 and smth1 appear more than twice. I know relational distance of entry2 vs other entries, as well as a relational distance of smth1 vs other smths, now I want to combine them into all the cases, given in table 1 and to move the point by axis3 - non-relational axis, corresponding to parameter `coefficient`.

Comment: So, what's the expected output? Is it `Table 3`?

Comment: @Divakar, no I want to merge all the three, so to have full descriptions of points and to perform clustering analysis. I can't actually imagine the full table and/or unable to write it in 2D, because there are at least two pair-wise comparisons. But I can more or less imagine it in space.

Comment: If you can mathematically explain or put up some psuedo-code on getting the output, would help us solve it, or else it looks like a guessing game.

Comment: @Divakar I have added some changes, please, let me know if it's clearer now) Thanks